# Sentence from song 小さな恋の歌

Tags: song-lyrics, particle-ほど

I'm not sure if I translate this passage from the song right:

ほら、あなたにとって、大事な人ほどすぐ側にいるの。

I'm not sure which perspective we're talking about. Is the other person right by my side because I'm important to him/her? Is the の at the end a nominalizer or as an explanation?

ただ、あなたにだけ、届いて欲しい響け恋の歌。

I assume this means that I want the song to reach just him/her. However, why is there the ただ? Is it a conjunction to the previous sentence and if yes why?

Also, what is the form of 響け here - the imperative? If yes, how does that fit into the sentence?

Comment: I disagree with the interpretation mentioned by someone else. My interpretation of the first line: "Hey look–you always tend to have the most important people closest to you."

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence means "The more important people are for you, the closer they are to you". This の indicates emotional emphasis, which is mainly used by female. ただ～だけ means "just only". I think this 響け is close to hope than the imperative and 響け恋の歌 is inversion.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on the first sentence? I would have never come to this conclusion :)

Comment: ～ほど～ means "The more ～, the more ～". For example, (聞けば)聞くほど興味深くなる(The more I hear, the more interested I become.)

Comment: Ok, i think I get it now, thanks! One more question, is the phrase in [] the predicate here:
[ただ、あなたにだけ、届いて欲しい響け恋の]歌。

Comment: The sentence would be usually 「ただ、あなたにだけ、恋の歌が届いて欲しい。恋の歌よ、響け!」. Lyrics has often unnormal grammar.